# Как можно тестировать производительность браузера для Web-страницы?

Tags: веб-программирование, javascript, тестирование, производительность, css

Здравствуйте.  
Как можно тестировать производительность браузера; 
Или еще лучше, производительность интернет-страницы (от загруженности элементами дизайна до выполнения `JavaScript`).
?????

Comment: Зачем делать одинаковые вопросы?

Comment: @Shrek, дайте ссылку на похожий вопрос.

Comment: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acid3 не то?

Comment: тест на поддержку браузером веб-стандартов ///   
  
Не, не то. я про производительность спрашивал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[page speed](http://code.google.com/intl/ru-RU/speed/page-speed/) и еще есть [java.console](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_API#console.count.28.5Btitle.5D.29) - тоже интересная штука

Answer (score 1):

Inspect element в Опере и Chrome, Файрбаг в файрфоксе.
Там есть вкладка соответствующая, показывающая все времена загрузки и исполнения.
Для тестирования скорости можно перезагрузить страницу раз 10-100 без кэширования.